Dependency Injection helper fluent UI
I am coding a NuGet package heavily inspired by Scrutor. I wanted to simplify Scrutor's fluent interface and improve its attribute-based class registration.
Thus, I'd like to gather some opinions and ideas to make it as clear, and easy to use as possible.
Given these sample classes:
public interface IService1 { string Value { get; set; } }
public interface IService2 { }
public abstract class Service1Base : IService1 { }
public class Implementation1 : Service1Base {  }
public class Implementation2 : Service1Base { }
public class Implementation3 : Service1Base { }
public class Implementation4 : IService2 { }
public class Implementation5 : IService2 { }

This is an example of how we could register them using my library´s fluent interface:
services
    .Register(classes => classes
        .FromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .Where(t => t.ExactlyAnyOf(typeof(Implementation1), typeof(Implementation2), typeof(Implementation3)))
            .Using<Scoped, AsSelf>()
        .AndAlso(t => t.Exactly<Implementation4>())
            .Using<Singleton>()
        .AndAlso(t => t.Exactly<Implementation5>())
            .Using<Transient, AsSelf>()

As key points of the fluent interface implementation:

Class sources are, for a lack of a better word "stackable", so we can have a FromAssemblyOf<Exception>().From(this.ListOfTypes) expression and it will apply whatever Using we place afterwards to the classes selected by both From expressions.
Using supports three type parameters (tho only two are shown in this particular example), first one is an IServiceLifeTimeStrategy, second an IMappingStrategy, and third an IRegistrationStrategy.
There are several overloads for Using, most notably, one that allows supplying instances of classes implementing the aforementioned interfaces, thus allowing extensibility.
When not provided, the default strategies are: Scoped, AsImplementedInterfaces and Add.
If we don't specify a From* method, the library will use DependencyContext.Default, thus having to check more assemblies, but also being a little bit less verbose:

services
    .Register(classes => classes
        .Where(t => t.ExactlyAnyOf(typeof(Implementation1), typeof(Implementation2), typeof(Implementation3)))
            .Using<Scoped, AsSelf>()
        .AndAlso(t => t.Exactly<Implementation4>())
            .Using<Singleton>()
        .AndAlso(t => t.Exactly<Implementation5>())
            .Using<Transient, AsSelf>()

Finally, on the attribute-based registration functionality, given these classes, decorated with the library attributes:
[Singleton<AsSelf>]
public class TestServiceDependency { }

public interface IScopedService { }

[Scoped]
public class TestScopedService(TestServiceDependency serviceDependency) : IScopedService
{
}

public interface ITransientService { }

[Transient]
public class TestTransientService(TestServiceDependency serviceDependency) : ITransientService
{
}

public interface ISingletonService { }

[Singleton]
public class TestSingletonService(TestServiceDependency serviceDependency) : ISingletonService
{
}

This single line would register them into DI, with the expected behavior:
services.RegisterByAttributes()

If you need more context, you can see the source code of the alpha version of the library.
I must apologize in advance for the lack of any sort of documentation, tho. The reason being that I want to gather all possible criticism and suggestions, change whatever needs to change, and then document the resulting code.

I would suggest to review it with Scrutor community instead. as you do not want to reinvent the wheel!, and might re-improve your plan to something that they will adhere. Plus, they will have better knowledge on Scrutor than here.

@iSR5 I really appreciate your answer. It hasn't occurred to me to ask there because this library could potentially replace Scrutor in the end. Not that it is really my aim, tho, I started by using Scrutor for the Dependency Attributes stuff, and end up thinking that why wouldn't I have my own Scrutor, with blackjack and hookers :)
